# How to Use Function Code 6 Modbus RTU library

Tags: arduino-mega, library, modbus

I'm trying to communicate with a temperature controller using Modbus RTU.
I used [this](https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino) Arduino library.

I was able to read PV(current temperature value) using below code. It uses Function code 4.

I want to set SV value(Set Value) using **Function code 6**

I replaced `telegram.u8fct = 0x04;` to `telegram.u8fct = 0x06;` and `telegram.u16RegAdd = 0x03E8;` to relevant address for SV. But, I couldn't get success.

How can I implement Function Code 6 in this library ?

Code for read PV as below. Its working properly.

```
    #include <ModbusRtu.h>

    // data array for modbus network sharing
    uint16_t au16data[16];
    uint8_t u8state;

    /**
        Modbus object declaration
        u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
        u8serno : serial port (use 0 for Serial)
        u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI
                     or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
    */
    //TRANSMISSION CONTROL PIN - 8
    //HADWARE SERIAL NUMBER - 2
    Modbus master(0, 2, 8); // this is master and RS-232 or USB-FTDI

    /*
       This is an structe which contains a query to an slave device
    */
    modbus_t telegram;

    unsigned long u32wait;

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      master.begin(9600); // baud-rate at 9600
      master.setTimeOut( 2000 ); // if there is no answer in 2000 ms, roll over
      u32wait = millis() + 1000;
      u8state = 0;
    }

    void loop() {
      switch ( u8state ) {
        case 0:
          if (millis() > u32wait) u8state++; // wait state
          break;
        case 1:
          telegram.u8id = 0x01; // slave address
          telegram.u8fct = 0x04; // function code (this one is registers read)
          telegram.u16RegAdd = 0x03E8; // start address in slave [CHANNEL 1 PV]
          telegram.u16CoilsNo = 0x01; // number of elements (coils or registers) to read
          telegram.au16reg = au16data; // pointer to a memory array in the Arduino

          master.query( telegram ); // send query (only once)
          u8state++;
          break;
        case 2:
          master.poll(); // check incoming messages
          if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE) {
            u8state = 0;
            u32wait = millis() + 100;
            Serial.println(au16data[0]);//PRINT TEMPARATURE VALUE
          }
          break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change SV value.

According to the library, when using function code 6, It get sending data(temperature value) from `au16regs[0]`as below piece of code of library file.
Need to setup that value before requesting.

(ModbusRtu.h - line number 601)

```
case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER: //if cunction code 6
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(au16regs[0]);
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte(au16regs[0]);
```

Comment: It's OK to accept you own answer as the solution to the problem.

Comment: @VE7JRO yes. Its the ansawer to question. But, you will have to face a problem if you use this code in program with other functions.